# How to Order by DateCreated with multiple OR condition in Parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfquery

I have a requirement where i will be fetching data from a table using multiple 'OR' conditions in multiple columns, like either data in a column has to match or data in another column has to match for retrieving a row. And once this condition satisfied i need all the eligible objects to be ordered in their creation date(createdAt).

Here is what i am doing:

```
PFQuery *query1=[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Messages"];
[query1 whereKey:@"Receiver" equalTo:@"some-id"];

PFQuery *query2=[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Messages"];
[query2 whereKey:@"ThreadID" equalTo:@"some-threadID"];

PFQuery *finalQuery=[PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[query1,query2]];
[finalQuery orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
NSArray *msgs=[query findObjects];
```

I am getting the messages but they are not lates, i.e. they are not sorted by 'createdAt'.

Can Anybody Help? Thanks

Comment: I remember this worked fine for me for my another app using Parse.

Comment: Put them all in one query instead of sub-queries.